# Syntax error when in a class but not out in the open?

Tags: php, php-parse-error

When I do:

```
class MyClass {
  public $copy = file_get_contents('somefile.mdown');
}
```

I get:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' \
in /file.php on line 25
```

I'm new to classes in PHP, but not to OOP.

I can, of course, just do file_get_contents outside of the class and all is well.  What's up with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
class MyClass 
{
   public var $copy;

   public function MyClass()
   {
      $this->copy = file_get_contents('somefile.mdown');
   }
};

$obj = new MyClass();
```

When I declare $copy in a class with

```
   public var $copy;
```

I'm saying "When I make a thing of type MyClass it will have a member variable called 'copy'".

Only when that class is created, and the constructor called (ie $obj = new MyClass), does $copy exist as part of some *thing* of type MyClass. In the constructor above (function MyClass) that *thing* is the $this variable, meaning "the current thing I was told to work on". In this case that might be $obj in the example above.

Cheers,
-Doug

Comment: This was what I was working on after I wrote the question, thanks!

Comment: Also, you need a `()` after MyClass, or else you get a syntax error.

Comment: cool thanks :) post is updated with correction.

Comment: Sorry ... `public function MyClass` needs to be `public function MyClass()`  Thanks again.