# Unknown Error in Syntax

Tags: php

While working with an OOP script in PHP upon parsing I get a syntax error I know shouldn't be there. The syntax is perfect.

```
class Organism
 {
  private $ex = array(0=>"Hello",1=>"world!");
  public $ex2 = array_rand($ex,1);
 }
```

Gives me the error of

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Basic PHP... you cannot initialize a class attribute with a dynamic result. Constants only. E.G: RTLM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error when in a class but not out in the open?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1653302)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you must implement constructor and assign default values for your variables there.

```
private $ex = array(0=>"Hello",1=>"world!"); // Will work (not a function/not dynamic)

public $ex2 = array_rand($ex,1);  //A function call won't work
```

Solution:

```
class Organism
 {
    private $ex = array(0=>"Hello",1=>"world!");
    public $ex2 ;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->ex2 = array_rand($this->ex,1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Little place for me to say this but $this->ex2 = array_rand($ex,1); needs to me $this->ex2 = array_rand($this->ex,1);